# C#, Checksum CRC-16/MCRF4XX

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, crc16

Does anyone know the calculate of CRC-16/MCRF4XX with C#? 
I tried with this code:

```
private static ushort Calc(byte[] x)
{
    ushort wCRC = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        wCRC ^= (ushort)(x[i] << 8);
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((wCRC & 0x8000) != 0)
                wCRC = (ushort)((wCRC << 1) ^ 0x1021);
            else
                wCRC <<= 1;
        }
    }
    return wCRC;
}
```

but the result doesn't match.

Comment: The result doesn't match with what?

Comment: i compare the result of that code with online checksum calc.but, the result match with CRC-16/XMODEM not with CRC-16/MCRF4XX.